# RSA calculating c^d mod n

Tags: encryption, rsa

In the RSA Encryption Algorithm, how would one calculate `c^d mod n` when `c` and `d` are large numbers?

Comment: There's a whole [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA) dedicated to this topic.

Comment: Better Wikipedia article: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation

Comment: Like for example I want to calculate 60889^69301 mod 87984. how to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[GMP](http://gmplib.org) is a C/C++ software library that does this for you: mpz_powm, mpz_powm_ui in the documentation. The method used is (largely) explained in [the wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation) and you could try to read the source code for GMP, if you feel up to that...

Answer (score 1):

The easy answer is: use a language and/or library which implements arithmetics on "big integers" and includes an appropriate function for modular exponentiation. In Java, this means using `java.lang.BigInteger`, specifically the method `modPow()`.

Since the underlying computers cannot really handle "integers" but a limited emulation thereof (e.g. "32-bit integers" which behave like integers except that upper bits beyond the 32nd are discarded), such "big integer" implementations must apply some specific algorithms, which are described in full detail in the [Handbook of Applied Cryptography](http://www.cacr.math.uwaterloo.ca/hac/) (chapter 14).

Answer (score 0):

The "powMod" operation can be taken down into smaller step.

For example `5 ^ 3 % 6` is equal `((5 * 5) % 6) * 5 % 6` and `5 ^ 4 % 6` is equal to `(((5 * 5) % 6) * 5 % 6) * 5 % 6)`. As you can see you can apply the modulo operation in the sub result of the exponent to always work with smaller number and thus make it easier to calculate `c ^ d % n` even when c and d are high value.

For more information :
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation

Comment: Hey thanks for the info. Suppose I want to calculate 60889^69301 mod 87984 . Is there any simpler process?

Comment: @Santosh Do you want to calculate this by hand or programmatically ?

Comment: @Santosh Unless you want to rewrite the hole modPow operation, the easier way is just to use library for big number. In Java there is the class called BigInteger which has the operation powMod which does exactly that.